# How can I make a textbox text as a hyperlink?

Tags: asp.net

How can I make a a textbox text as a hyperlink?
I have a asp.net text box for a user to enter his/her email
in and I wanted to show the entered text as a hyperlink.
How can I make this possible?

Comment: I have just a suggestion not an answer; Indulge with `CSS` thoroughly.

Answer (score 1):

Don't think you can. What you could do is make an onclick event for the textbox.
Or you can make a custom control that inharits from TextBox and implement this.

Answer (score 0):

You could change the `textarea` element to a `a`-element with Javascript